# Working with Subversive (SVN) and Symfony2. 'Vendor' folder don't upload

Tags: eclipse, symfony, svn

I recently started a new web project and I decided to use **Symfony2** as a framework, **Eclipse** as IDE and **Subversive** as plugin for version control.

My idea was to make the '*commit*' of all modifications, ignoring yes, folder '*logs*' and '*cache*' of the web application.

My surprise came when I imported the first Symfony project to the repository, when I do the commit, the folder '*vendor*' where they are stored dependencies framework is unaffected, ie it is **not uploaded to the repository**. If I make changes to this folder, Subversive also treats it as modified files stored in the repository.

It is probably because I have not worked much with a management system versioning and something is going wrong, but do not understand why the folder '*vendor*', which is critical for Symfony, not imported, even without any configuration to ignore files when performing '*commit*'.

**Thank you all.**

**A greetings.**

> *PS: Even without any configuration, installing the development environment, the plugin to version control and creating a Symfony
>   project from scratch, Subversive ignores the vendor folder.*

Comment: You should not store the `vendor` folder in your repository either: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html#initial-project-setup

Comment: #1 So when a developer wants to first download the latest version of the project to work with him ... Where does this and supposed to run these units? Because without them you can not work: S

Comment: You should store your `composer.lock` file and build your dependencies by `composer install`.

Comment: Yes! Just try to do just that when I read your answer. Thank you.

Topic closed.

: D

Comment: You are welcome! Please read the whole documentation page carefully — it explains why you should not store `vendors` in your repository.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of chapay is very good : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_svn.html#initial-project-setup

this line helps me, not on symfony but in another project with composer where I didn't wanted to commit the vendor folder, only the composer.json :

svn propset svn:ignore "vendor" .